# Iterating through string C++

Tags: c++

I have a c++ program where I need to iterate through a string and print the characters.  I get the correct output but along with the output I get some garbage values(garbage value is 0).  I don't know why i get those values?  Can anyone help me with that?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int number_needed(string a) {
   for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
   {
       cout<<a[i];
   }
}

int main(){
    string a;
    cin >> a;
    cout << number_needed(a) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

sample Input

```
hi
```

Output

```
hi0
```

Comment: Please compile your code with `-Wall` or with `/W3` and don't ignore warnings, you'll see the problem then. Thanks!

Comment: `number_needed` the name has nothing to do with what it does.

Comment: `number_needed()` _should_ be declared as `number_needed(string const &a)` --- otherwise you're _copying_ the string unnecessarily.

Comment: You should also just use `string::const_iterator`.

Comment: I'm really astounded to see this upvoted three times. What is good about this post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

`cout << number_needed(a) << endl;`

Change it to just:

`number_needed(a);`

The problem is that `number_needed()` is outputting each letter of the string, but after that, you're outputting the value returned by `number_needed()`, which is 0.

Comment: It doesn't have to be 0, it is undefined behavior.

Comment: Much of this doesn't look correct to me. Why do you way the returned value is zero?

Comment: @SebastianJohnHoward: He's saying that the returned value is zero, _because that is what's printed_. Of course, Rakete1111 has a valid point that it's Undefined Behavior. Anything _might_ have happened, but we can safely assume that the computer did not actually catch fire.

Answer (score 5):

The behaviour of your program is *undefined*. `number_needed` is a non-`void` function so therefore it needs an explicit `return` value on all program control paths.

It's difficult to know what you want the `cout` in `main` to print. Judging by your question text, you may as well change the return type of `number_needed` to `void`, and adjust `main` to

```
int main(){
    string a;
    cin >> a;
    number_needed(a);
    cout << endl; // print a newline and flush the buffer.
    return 0;
}
```